# Grabbing the digits of a number without using division or modulus

Tags: vhdl, digits, integer-division

I am trying to implement a 7-segment counter using VHDL.

The counter starts from 0 and increments an integer value to a max of 9999.

The value is passed to a bloc that is supposed to "split" the number into digits so that i can display them on the 7-segment which are multiplexed...

I have already done this on a PIC using many methods such as Interrupts... but now that i am trying to do this on a FPGA (Xilinx Spartan 3E Starter Board to be exact) i noticed while implementing the code i've wrote that i can't use neither division nor modulus because they cannot be implemented...

**Edit:** I know i could just map the values 0..9999 each alone but that is far far fetched.

Surely there is another way, but i can't think of it.

Any hint on a workaround would be very appreciated!

Comment: Is your number stored as binary or decimal?

Comment: its in decimal, but if its best to have it in binary i can easily convert it

Comment: Well, if your number is in decimal, just extract the bits containing each digit and send them to your display multiplexor. The LSD is `num[3:0]`, the MSD is `num[15:12]`, etc.

Comment: cool i didn't know i could do that, im still missing something tho, i tried this `D0 <= count[3:0];` and i get `';' expected` error on that line (was compiling before)

EDIT: D0 is a 4 bit unsigned out signal

Comment: nevermind, i forgot the syntax is : `D0 <= count(3 downto 0);` will test and get back here :)

Comment: all is good thanks ! why don't you put your answer below so that i can mark it as accepted ! Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your number is in decimal, just extract the bits containing each digit and send them to your display multiplexor. The LSD is num[3:0], the MSD is num[15:12], etc.